# CSS and js files not working while passing asp-route-id as Guid Id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When trying to pass a Guid through [asp-route-id="@residence.Id/*Guid*/"] The CSS and Js files do not load. Chacked everything by using Breakpoints etc. Action Method receives the Guid Parameter and everything alse works fine.

[image: Only Html getting Displayed]

This is the view from where i pass Guid parameter.

```
@foreach (var residence in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-3">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="@Url.Content(residence.ResidenceImage)" alt="@residence.Name">

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">@residence.Name</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">@residence.Description</p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                            <a asp-controller="Residences" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@residence.Id" class="btn btn-outline-info"><span class="tf-icons bx bx-detail"></span>&nbsp;Details</a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="tf-icons bx bx-book-add"></span>&nbsp;Book</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

This is the action method Of the view.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var residence = await _context.Residence
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (residence == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(residence);
        }
```

Tried action method without parameter and without asp-route-id then view works fine.

Comment: I tested your code and there is no problem. How do you load the Css and Js files? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The CSS and Js files work fine on other views without the Guid parameter. I have used CSS and Js file reference tags In partial views and referenced partial views in _layout.cshtml file.

Comment: Hi @Babar Hussain, I put the Css and Js references in the partial view according to your description, but there is still no problem. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: of course, there would not be any problem with that my problem is caused by Guid being passed in the action method that returns the view with CSS and Js errors. i Can't provide a minimal reproducible example.